# How to add table to vue2-editor component?

Tags: vue.js

i want to add table to vue2-editor component

[image]

ref
https://githubz.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor

Comment: It could be better to check the docs whether table functionality provided. if yes there may be some way to enable it.

Comment: there is a dependency on Quill in the 
https://githubz.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor/blob/master/src/helpers/markdown-shortcuts.js, there is no support https://quilljs.com/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

Quill by default doesn't support tables very well and would require a custom module. Unfortunately, the two main table modules for Quill are built on Quill 2x (in development) and vue2Editor is built on Quill 1.3x. They aren't compatible and due to some fundamental changes in QUill 2 this will never work.

Sadly Quill is also pretty much assumed dead. There hasn't been any development in forever and the developer doesn't seem to respond to issues.

I was also using Quill but had to switch for all sorts of reasons.

I would suggest trying something like ckEditor. Works with vue2, properly maintained, allows for custom modules etc.. and is just a better quality editor IMO